# Error at converting string to double in c#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, double

i'm having problems converting a string to double. I'm using the Double.Parse method but it keeps crashing saying that there is this "Entry character chain with incorrect format". The string I'm trying to convert is this one : `21.00000000`. Is it not supported by this function? If so, why not?
This is the line of the error `acc.Latitude = double.Parse(accounts.Lat)`.

Best regards.

Comment: please provide your code sample

Comment: need to see what you are doing wrong to be able to fix it

Comment: `acc.Latitude = double.Parse(accounts.Lat)` being acc.Latitude double and accounts.Lat is the number I mentioned before that I receive

Comment: And now the exact error message...? Also: Are you sure that the error really occurs where you think it does? It would be rather strange if an exception about `DateTime` occurred when parsing a double...

Comment: what are the contents in `accounts.Lat`?

Comment: First off check your regional settings, "," and "." varies depending on the settings. Control Panel -> Region -> Additional Settings.. -> Decimal Symbol. Use the one stated there (or change it)

Comment: @Nicholas: Either way it won't crash, just give a different result. Just verfied this with LinqPad. I don't think the exception comes from this statement.

Comment: accounts.Lat is `21.00000000` as I said before. The exact error message is in portuguese and the thing related to the datetime isn't associated with this problem after all as I've encapsulated it on a try catch. I'm going to do my best to translate it: "Entry character chain with incorrect format"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually due to regional settings. I've switched the `.` for `,` and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Double.TryParse` inestad in order to prevent whring input. This method returns `true` if the input-string can be parsed. In this case the `out`-param contains the actual `double`-value:

```
double value;
if (Double.TryParse(accounts.Lat, out value;)) 
{ 
    /* do something with the value */
}
```